# Seriously need help on how to write a lesson on Algebraic expressions and equations?

Tags: equations, templates

I'm a grade eight student who really needs help. I have to write a lesson/ how to paper on how to solve algebraic expressions and equations, but  don't know how to start or anything! I could really use a template or just some tips and help.

Comment: Are you using `LaTeX` to write your paper or do you want to use it for solving equations? `LaTeX` will not solve your equations as, say, `Maple` would do...

Comment: I have made Steven B. Segletes' template available [here](https://www.writelatex.com/1184416fdbybz#/2836193/).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3):

Start with this, and fill in your own text and equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a numbered equation
\begin{equation}
  y = mx + b
\end{equation}

In a new paragraph, here is an unnumbered equation
\[
  y = Ax^2 + bx + c
\]
If you want the equation inline, then this $y = mx + b$ should suffice.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) package should be included as this seems to be a math doc.